# How to pass element data into a case when using a switch statement in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, switch-statement

I have a tab component in my application and I wrote a function to switch between the tabs. First I wanna test if this works. I have tried in the past with the `if` statement and this is working good (see comment code). Now I want to try it with a `switch` statement. This is my code for the function:

```
switchAdvancedView(elem) {
    //if (elem.data('id') === 'recentview') {
    //    alert('view1');
    //}
    //else if (elem.data('id') === 'myview') {
    //    alert('view2');
    //}
    //else if (elem.data('id') === 'systemview') {
    //    alert('view3');
    //}
    switch (elem) {
        case elem.data('id') === 'recentview':
            alert('view 1');
            break;
        case elem.data('id') === 'myview':
            alert('view 2');
            break;
        case elem.data('id') === 'myview':
            alert('view 3');
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

The problem is it doesn't fire the alert function when I click on a tab.

I have used this source:

Link: https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-switch-statement/

The tutorials shows only with a hardcode value.

How can I pass the element.data id to the case of the switch statement?

Comment: show your html part. and from where you use that function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the default switch format looks like:

```js
function switchAdvancedView(text) {
  switch (text) {
    case 'recentview':
      alert('view 1');
      break;
    case 'myview':
      alert('view 2');
      break;
    case 'myview':
      alert('view 3');
      break;
    default:
  }
}

switchAdvancedView("recentview");
```

You can also have more advanced conditions, i.e.:

```js
function switchAdvancedView(text, otherFlag) {
  switch (text) {
    case otherFlag ? text : null :
      alert("OtherFlag is true");
      break;
    case 'recentview':
      alert('view 1');
      break;
    case 'myview':
      alert('view 2');
      break;
    case 'myview':
      alert('view 3');
      break;
    default:
  }
}

switchAdvancedView("recentview", true);
```

But for the above example to work you need to make sure that those types of conditions are on the top so that of the switch (unless you want that specific order).

Though I personally prefer this format over switch statements:

```js
function switchAdvancedView(text) {
  ({
    recentview: () => alert("view 1"),
    myview: () => alert("view 2"),
    myview2: () => alert("view 3")
  }[text] || (_ => _))();
}

switchAdvancedView("recentview");
```

Comment: Glad I could help, Did you understand how the last examples work? Would like any further help?

Comment: Yes, I have played with your code and I understand it perfectly. Thank you so much for the great explanation.